# How can I move files into a folder based on their name?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, script, batch-file

I have several .pdf and .tex-files in a certain folder "ABC".

They all are named by the scheme

```
C01S02_Word.pdf
C03S02SS01_Description_random_words.pdf
C04S01SS02_More_words.pdf
and so forth
```

*C* in this scheme stands for chapter, *S* for section and *SS* for subsection. So in the folder ABC I also have the folder for each chapter, simply named *C01*, *C02* and so forth. In each chapter folder I have one folder named *Pictures*.

Could someone please write a batch script so I could move all .tex and .pdf files in their respective *Pictures*-folder, `C04S01SS02_More_words.pdf` would get moved to `C04/Pictures` and `C01S02_Word.pdf` to `C01/Pictures` and so forth?

Note: [of course I googled this already](https://www.google.de/search?num=50&q=windows+7+batch+script+move+files+based+on+name) but so far I was unable to convert all the many bits into a working script. I do not want to do T&E runs anymore. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create this batch file:

```
@echo off
for %%F in (*.pdf *.tex) do call :subr "%%F"
exit /b

:subr
set filename=%1
move %1 %filename:~1,3%\Pictures
exit /b
```

Notes:

- `for %%F in (*.pdf *.tex) do …` performs the following statement
  once for each filename that matches `*.pdf` or `*.tex`, with `%%F` set to the filename.
- `call :subr "%%F"` invokes the bottom three lines of the script,
  with the first argument (`%1`) set to `"%%F"` (the filename, quoted).
- `exit /b` exits the script without blowing away the Command Prompt window.
- `set filename=%1` copies the filename argument into the `filename` variable.
- `move` moves a file.
- `%variable:~start,len%`
  takes the indicated substring of `%variable%` (the first character is #0),
  so `%filename:~1,3%` is the first three characters of `%filename%`. 
  (The count starts at 0; I’m using 1 to skip the `"`.)
- `exit /b` returns from the subroutine.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Hm, does this account for `Pictures` folder? Do I just have to write `%filename:~0,3%/Pictures` for that?

Comment: The FOR loop does not work. It only works on one file.

Comment: I think it has to do with spaces in the filename. If I remove the spaces in a filename, it works with said file.

Comment: That being said, I can't figure out how to use `delims=` here since this code snippet is a bit different from all theothers ones I found on the net

Comment: D’oh! I misread the question. Change `%filename:~0,3%` to `%filename:~0,3%\Pictures`. And d’oh again! You can handle filenames with space characters in them by changing `%%F` to `"%%F"` and then changing `%filename:~0,3%\Pictures` to `%filename:~1,3%\Pictures`. You shouldn’t need `delims=`.

Comment: Hm, ok, but I don't understand this at all. The first three characters are always the "correctly put"-ones. Later on, after the first underscore, a space might occur. But is `~1,3` then still the right way to do this?

Comment: I don't understand your meta-question. Have you tried my script? Does it do what you need? It seems to work for me, but I haven't tested it exhaustively. If it doesn't work correctly for you, tell me what happens, and I'll see if I can figure out how to fix it.  But, if it produces the results you want, and you still have a question, you'll need to be a bit more specific.